# How to disable row updates after 1 update in SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php page using a mySQL server, after I update a row with any data, I would like this specific row to be locked from any further updates.

Is there a way to do it in PHP or SQL?

Comment: Just add some additional logic in your PHP code which is for updating: When you first update the row, put something in a column in that row which shows it's been updated before. Then when you're updating, you can check the content of that column before you run the update. If there is already data in it, you know the row has already been updated in the past, so you can return an error message to the user instead of executing the requested update. Additionally you could check this when you're displaying items on the page too, so you don't even offer the "update" option in the UI for those items

Comment: Thank you, I managed to come up with a solution!